# gwt-tree css style

Tags: css, gwt, styling, gwt-widgets

I am having difficulty styling the gwt-tree widget.

I have used

```
.gwt-Tree {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0066CC;
    width: 14.5em !important;
}

.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    margin-left: -1.5px !important;
    }
```

But I can still see the padding. Also I want to increase the size of tree item (+) . Any pointers will be hwlpful.

Google search yielded this which didnt work.

```
.gwt-Tree > div:first-child {
  width: 0px !important;
  height: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}

.gwt-Tree > div {
        padding: 0px 5px !important;
}

.gwt-Tree > div[hidefocus=true] {

        width: 0px !important;
        height: 0px !important;

        margin: 0px !important;
        padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Any sort of help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your padding isn't working because the parent div on a `gwt-TreeItem` has an inline style with padding. The `div` also doesn't have an id. So the `gwt-TreeItem` correctly has no padding-left, but it is still indented due to its *parent*'s padding-left.

Comment: Thanks. so hw do I not inherit from parent. Also hw to increae + size?

Comment: You can't select the parent from the child using CSS, I think. You may be able to write a custom JS function. I didn't post as an answer because I wasn't actually sure how to solve your problem. To increase + size you may need to swap out a bigger image and then change the CSS `height` and `width`.